# Quartz cron expression of 0/0

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

As a part of a input validation I was thinking whether this is a really valid cron expression and how it would executed:

```
0 0/0 * * * ?
```

Quartz validation returns true

```
org.quartz.CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 0/0 * * * ?")
```

So, does this run all the time, never, every hour or every minute...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) documentation:

> - `/` - used to specify increments. For example, "0/15" in the seconds field means "*the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45*". And "5/15" in the seconds field means "*the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50*". You can also specify '/' after the '' character - in this case '' is equivalent to having '0' before the '/'. '1/3' in the day-of-month field means "fire every 3 days starting on the first day of the month".

This means `0` doesn't really make sense in this context. However [`CronExpression`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) seems to ignore it and simply discard that value, effectively treating this expressions as:

```
0 0 * * * ?
```

If you are curious, [this is the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.3/org/quartz/CronExpression.java/#970) that discards invalid `0` value:

```
    if ((incr == 0 || incr == -1) && val != ALL_SPEC_INT) {
        if (val != -1) {
            set.add(Integer.valueOf(val));
        } else {
            set.add(NO_SPEC);
        }

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can find the result by using [TriggerUtils.computeFireTimesBetween()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html#computeFireTimesBetween%28org.quartz.spi.OperableTrigger,%20org.quartz.Calendar,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date%29) :

```
try {
        CronTriggerImpl cron = new CronTriggerImpl();

        cron.setStartTime(new Date());
        cron.setCronExpression("0 0/0 * * * ?");

        BaseCalendar calendar = new BaseCalendar();
        List<Date> result = TriggerUtils.computeFireTimesBetween(cron, calendar, new Date(),DateBuilder.futureDate(1, IntervalUnit.DAY));

        for (Date date : result) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the output is :

```
Thu Apr 05 18:00:00 CST 2012
Thu Apr 05 19:00:00 CST 2012
Thu Apr 05 20:00:00 CST 2012
Thu Apr 05 21:00:00 CST 2012
Thu Apr 05 22:00:00 CST 2012
Thu Apr 05 23:00:00 CST 2012
Fri Apr 06 00:00:00 CST 2012
Fri Apr 06 01:00:00 CST 2012
Fri Apr 06 02:00:00 CST 2012
Fri Apr 06 03:00:00 CST 2012
Fri Apr 06 04:00:00 CST 2012
.......................
```

So , `0 0/0 * * * ?` will run at every hour at 0 mins and 0 sec.

Answer (score 1):

More information at [CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) documentation. My guess is that the expression `0 0/0 * * * ?` means *once every hour* (i.e. `0/0` does not denote every minute). However, if you need all the time (i.e. every second), you can use `* * * * ? *`.